# Contacts Provider Android for Enterprise

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-dialer, android-for-work

This may not be something that is possible but I have tried a few things.

When creating a contact while mid-call, the dialer updates itself with the new contact information.
This does not happen when the contact is created in an Android for Enterprise work profile (While mid-call).

Are the contacts in the personal profile and the work profile searched differently on incoming calls ?

I tested this by manually filling out a new contact, didnt save it, but had it ready to be saved.
I then called the phone and created the new contact while the phone was already ringing.
After a second or two, the name of the newly created contact showed up in the still ringig dialer.

When doing the same thing, but creating the contact in the Android for Enterprise Work Profile, this does not work. The dialer does not update while the phone is still ringing.
Only after I canceled the call, I can see a missed call, that is displays this contact information.

If the contact exists in the Work Profile before the call comes in, all works fine.

The reason I try this is that not everyone in the company has everyones contacts saved.
So I want to check the caller when the call comes in to display the correct name of the colegue calling.

Maybe my approach is wrong. Any ideas ?